# Make Column Read-Only in Edit Form

Tags: read-only

I am attempting to lock down some fields in the Edit Form so that the data cannot be accidentally changed.

I am knowledgeable of how to use script and content editor web parts, so I am able to insert script.

I tried this script, but it did nothing:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"
       type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
//Set the Field to Read only and change its background colour
$("input[title='Metrics ID']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
//You can disable the field also:  $("input[Title='Metrics ID']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

</script>
```

Any advice or resources would be very appreciated. Thanks!
Oh, and I am working in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: You can also check this [Set Field as Read-only in Edit Form In SharePoint](http://itcore.devoworx.net/read-only-field-in-edit-form-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SPUtility.js for hide and read only fields in SharePoint forms.

Reference link: https://sputility.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks. Is this easy to implement for someone who is not familiar with javascript?

Comment: Yes very easy just need to add this JS reference file and then put your read-only code in document.Ready().

Comment: Add the reference file to the Site Assets and connect to it with a Content Editor? Sorry, I've only done what I consider simple script additions.

Comment: Yes add file into site assets and then reference that file into content editor web part.

Comment: Got it. I found this step by step guide. http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Home
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Just-JQuery**

Looking at [sputility in GitHub](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility) -- it replaces `<input>`s and other fields with plain text, which is a good way to communicate read-only-ness.

Similarly, you can hide the input field and put the text value right after it:

```
var $metricsId = $("input[title='Metrics ID']");  // In case you're gonna use it again
$metricsId.hide().after($metricsId.val());        // Hide input element & put value after it.
```